# remove rest of line after n characters for specific line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have multiple files which have too many characters in the first line. I would line to trim the first line only after n characters. the characters to remove after different in every file and the characters before those to be removed. The rest of the lines of the file I need to remain unchanged.

For example

```
123456789123456789
important
important
important
```

will become

```
123456789
important
important
important
```

I have got this so far:

```
for i in *.txt; do sed -r 's/(.{10}).*/\1/' $i; done
```

but this trims all the lines, I only want to trim the first line and I cant figure out how to make it only apply to line 1.

Comment: This is not what I mean. I know to use sed but I cant figure out how to only use it on the first line. for i in *.txt; do sed -r 's/(.{10}).*/\1/' $i; done I was using but this removes from all the lines. I need to only edit the first.

Comment: thanks for showing your research! I retracted my downvote and upvoted. if you continue another search for "**replace first line only**" as said, you can resolve your question by yourself

Comment: I didnt realise this, thanks! I promise I did my research but I really havent found anything

Comment: @cats123 use `for i in *.txt; do sed -r '1s/(.{10}).*/\1/' $i; done not the '1' before the s to apply only to line 1.